# UILabel alignment of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How would I align UILabel attributed text vertically and to the left horizontally?
thanks

```
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

centers text both vertically and horizontally: the latter my designer does not fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the `alignment` property to `.left`. `UILabel` by default centers the text vertically:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .left
```